# X230 touchpad stops working after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, x230

I have upgraded to 16.04 and now whenever I do some typing, the touchpad stops working after a few seconds on my Lenovo X230. Not working means I cannot control the cursor nor tap on the touchpad but the buttons work.

Logging out and in makes it work again. I didn't have problems under 14.04.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Touchpad is still listed when it doesn't work:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/258335/75050
- https://askubuntu.com/a/873920/75050, doesn't work for me
- https://askubuntu.com/a/824659/75050, doesn't work for me
- https://askubuntu.com/a/288499/75050 and https://askubuntu.com/a/721045/75050 (reload driver), works but kind of inconvenient to do again and again

Comment: Just to add that reloading the driver once (as described in one of the links) seems to fix the issue for the whole session.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.£ days ago On my ubuntu 16.04 LTS started to do problem with touch pad. When I try to touch the right bar with icons all screen get crazy...All bar with icons disappear for few seconds, even the corner with clock and date. all screen becoming purple with nothing on and everything flashing . I installed again yesterday and i used without updates and was fine. over night i run updates and today , same problem. i think is something regarding updates . I think you can try to reinstall without updates and see how is work.. if is working fine this mean your laptop is fine...If is about updates...we need to wait for developers to solve this problem.I am not good with this think but i answer you hare just to let you know - you are not alone with problems on 16.04 LTS. All this thinks started  last week. I hope somebody will help you and will help me too. I have a question too regarding this but so far nobody answer me. Good look anyway